# Is trading between players available in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

I just finished a single player session and I found a nice item, for the `Soldier` class, but I am playing `Siren`.

I never played co-op till now and I would like to know if it is possible trade items with other human players in some way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not through any sort of UI, but you can drop items on the ground.  While in a co-op game with a friend, open up  the inventory screen, highlight the item, and press Spacebar (or something else if you're talking about non-PC  platforms - it will say across the bottom).  Your friend can pick it up.

Note that you can't currently trade items among your own characters without routing through a separate player to do so (at least not that I have heard).

Comment: Yeah... that's the only way unfortunately. Definitely a big oversight if you ask me.

Comment: For player trading is ok, thank you! You also answered to another possible question. I can't trasfer items to other characters in my profile? This is really bad :(

Comment: Note: When you trade an item with a friend, *make sure you both save* before you exit. A friend of mine accidentally lost a rare item when trying to trade it through someone because one of them forgot to walk up to the save post before they exited.

Comment: On the PS3 I've used a split screen game to trade amongst characters in the same profile.  This is probably as direct as it gets though it takes a bit of controller juggling.

Answer (score 4):

I made a trade between my own characters by starting two instances of Borderlands on the same PC. On first I created a new LAN game, on second I connected to it and marked as ready, return back to first and started the game.

It was running quite fine and with some ALT-TABs I was able to exchange items. I'm just not sure how much powerful your PC needs to be to run two instances of the game or if you need an active network interface (thus this may not work when your PC is completely offline).

Comment: Interesting. Is this allowed by game policies or do I risk to be banned for cheating or something else?

Comment: Well as long as you do this for singleplayer sessions only then it should be OK (I gave the Boneshredder SMG which drops from the Bonehead boss to my siren alt to make the character startup easier). But using this method to increase your PvP chances would be at least unfair.